# Using PowerShell and TFS.exe to update and delete files from projects

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, tfs

I am using PowerShell to modify a series of configuration files within a solution.  The solution is under TFS 2010 control.

The solution has many projects and the configuration files are all xml files.  The easy part is if I just need to modify a file, I check it out using the checkout command then save the file when I'm done.  All good.  I go into Visual Studio and see the modified files are updated with pending changes as I would expect

The part I'm having difficulty with is when I have a configuration file that is no longer needed and can be deleted.  Using the delete command does, in fact, mark the file for a pending delete, but it does not modify the project file where the deleted file is contained.

When I delete a file via Visual Studio, it automatically checks out and modifies the project file for me.  I'm not getting the same result when using a command line delete.

It's not practical for me to do this by hand as I am eliminating over 1,000 files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: The problem seems to be more how to script the Visual Studio delete-command.

Answer (score 2):

There are two components at work here.  When you are running inside VS, the project system processes all file commands (adds, deletes, edits, etc.) and then calls into the TFS Object Model to actually pend the changes in TFS.  The project system is also the one responsible here for removing the reference from the project file.  The TFS OM has no knowledge of whether a file is part of a project or not when it is run outside of Visual Studio.

If you have a list of the xml files that you need to delete your best bet is to write a script that reads these in and removes them from the project file (after pending an edit on the project file, of course).

-Taylor,
TFS Version Control Development Lead

Comment: I was afraid the answer might be along those lines.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: Actually, just one more question if you don't mind.  Is there a way to do this by running the script from within VS using the DTE if I know the project associated with the file I need to remove?

Comment: I am not sure off of the top of my head. I'll do some research today and try to get back to you soon.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your responses.  After much digging and trial and error, I figured it out.  It was way more simple than I was making it.

In short, I used DTE and ran my script from within VS using the PowerShell console.  It went something like this:

```
$mySolution = $dte.Solution
$projectItem = $mySolution.FindProjectItem($fileToRemove)

if ( $projectItem -ne $null )
{                    
    $projectItem.Remove()                    
}
```

Executing the Remove() command on the ProjectItem checks out the corresponding project and edits it accordingly.

Again, thank you again for the time you all took to look at my question and respond.  Hope this helps someone else someday!